# sql select count with group, add null value if no result found

Tags: mysql

I have three table which i want to count each row with group from another table column.
The problem is count with group will return nothing when no record found.
So i want to add null value for each group that no record found.

Here is the query:

```
select monster.monster_name,count(*) as count
from monster right join monster_ability 
on monster.monster_id= monster_ability.monster_id  where    
isnull(monster_ability.used) 
group by monster.monster_id
```

here is the fiddle: [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e7c23)

I want the result should look like this:

```
| monster_name | count |
|--------------|-------|
|         kora |     1 |
|      lowdowu |     3 |
|      ngjengeh|   null|
|       lortyu |     1 |
|     foh du fy|   null|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `case when` to get null when count is 0:

```
select
    m.monster_name,
    case when count(a.ability_id) = 0 then null else count(a.ability_id) end as `count`
from monster m
left join monster_ability ma on m.monster_id = ma.monster_id and ma.used is null
left join ability a on ma.ability_id = a.ability_id
group by m.monster_id
```

SQLFiddle [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e7c23/6) here.